# tvOS Table View layout Issues

Tags: swift, xcode, tvos

I am using tableviews in my tvOS application. The screen is divided into 3 table views. The left and right table view is indenting the header, the middle has no issues at all. I have tried the following to remove this indent but it is not working at all. Any help would be appreciated.

```
cell.focusStyle = .custom
cell.selectionStyle = .none

table.dataSource = self
table.delegate = self
table.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
table.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = false
table.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqb0E.png)

I believe this is caused by the Safe Area, but when unchecking this it does not work also

[Safe Area Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX9fk.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is not much more information I can add